# a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^n}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is the question I am trying to see the solution of part (a) in it:

Fix $\mathbb F_p$ a field with $p$ elements for $p$ prime. Consider $f(X) = X^{p^n} - X + 1$ over $\mathbb F_p$ and let $E$ be a splitting field of $f.$

$(a)$ Prove that $E$ has a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{p^n}.$

**My questions are:**

1-Why the following hint will prove part $(a)$?

The hint is: If $\alpha$ is a root of $f,$ produce more roots of the form $\alpha + a$

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the field $E' := \mathbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha)$. [Note that $\alpha$ is not in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Indeed, if $\alpha$ were already in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ then $\alpha$ would satisfy $\alpha^{p^n}-\alpha = 0$ and thus $\alpha$ would not be a root of $X^{p^n}-X+1$. ] Then $X^{p^n}-X+1$ completely splits in $E'$. [Indeed, let $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Then $\alpha +a \in E'$ is a root of $X^{p^n}-X+1=0$. [Indeed, $$(\alpha+a)^{p^n} = \alpha^{p^n}+a^{p^n},$$ as $E'$ is characteristic $p$, and $a^{p^n}=a$ as $a$ is in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.] So all $p^n$ roots of $X^{p^n}-X+1$ are accounted for in $E'$.] Thus on the one hand, the field $E$ as defined in the OP is a subfield of $E'$. On the other hand, every root of $X^{p^n}-X+1$ is in $E$ and thus, $\alpha +a$ is in $E$ for each $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. As $\alpha$ itself is also in $E$, it follows that $(\alpha+a) - \alpha =$ $a$ is in $E$ for each $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. And so the result follows.